# Fatal error on auth login

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-model

Im getting the following error when trying to log in a user:

```
Call to a member function login() on a non-object
```

My login action uses an external model. The action is:

```
public function login() {

        $this->loadModel('User');

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

           $theUser = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'])));    

            if($theUser['User']['activated'] == TRUE){

                if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){

                   $this->Session->setFlash('Logged in successfully');

                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'));
                } else {

                    $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
                }
            }else $this->Session->setFlash('User not yet activated. Please Contact administrator.');
        }
    }
```

The request data being passed to the `$this->Auth->login` is:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'admin'
    )
)
```

`$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` is the line causing the fatal error.

Can someone please explain what exactly the error means and what might be causing it?

Comment: It's listed above on the second line:

'Call to a member function login() on a non-object'

Comment: have you included Auth component ?

Comment: just noticed, why are you loading your User model explicitly ?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? Since CakePHP 2.x, passing data to 'Auth->login()' will automatically log in, **even if the password is incorrect** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to check that you've included the Auth component in the controller. For example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Auth'
    );

    public function login() { ... }
}
```

As pointed out by @thaJeztah - check [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) for correct usage, as your code (which based on the usage of `$this->request`, implies you're using 2.x) is not correct and will not test if the user exists and can login - but instead directly log the user in whatever they put in the login form.